# Saving utf-8 text as ansi file in python

Tags: python, utf-8, character-encoding, codepages

```
with open("C:/temp/Python/infile.csv", "r", encoding="utf-8") as csv:
    for line in csv:
        line = line.strip()
        cells = line.split(";")

        lastname = cells[49] 
        street_2nd_line = cells[52]
        city = cells[54]        

        #Convert to XML in ANSI
        with open("C:/temp/Python/outfile.txt", "w", encoding="ansi") as order:
            text =  lastname + "\n" + street_2nd_line + "\n" + city 
            print(text)
            order.write(text)
```

Hello,

I am opening a CSV file in UTF-8 and trying to store it to another file as ANSI. It works fine for German letters (I work on an German Windows). But if Python finds Slovenian characters, it stops at the "order.write" line with message

```
return mbcs_encode(input, self.errors)[0]
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'mbcs' codec can't encode characters in position 0--1: invalid character

If I try to do it that way with codecs:

`with codecs.open("C:/temp/Python/infile.csv", "r", encoding="utf-8") as csv:`
and
`with codecs.open("C:/temp/Python/outfile.txt", "w", encoding="ansi") as order:`

than I get the message:

> File "", line 721, in write
> File "", line 377, in write
> UnicodeEncodeError: 'mbcs' codec can't encode characters in position 0--1: invalid character

If I change the target encoding from ansi to cp1252, I get the error:

> File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
> return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u010c' in position 9: character maps to

The printout print(text) to the python shell works properly:

Testuser Čergiu
D.Š. : 12345678
Hoče

The problem occurs only by trying to save it.

How can I convert and store it properly?

Comment: What do you mean with "ANSI"? You know, ANSI is an association, with a lot of papers and standards. CP1252 (check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) doesn't support many Easter European languages. We have Unicode for a reason.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi FWIW, using [`ansi`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#text-encodings) as the encoding means to use Window's "ansi codepage" (CP_ACP). The naming is terrible, but it's what we're stuck with.

Comment: Could you clarify why you need to save the CSV file with that particular encoding?

Comment: @Brian61354270: yeah, but here in SO we use a lot ANSI also for "ANSI Escape codes" (also not really ANSI), which BTW can do shift encoding and load 4 different "Latin-X" extensions in parallel and so solving the problem here (if some libraries support such old shift encodings, which usually are not)

Comment: That `position 0--1` looks like an error message bug.  It should give the actual position of the error like the 2nd error message.  `ansi` will use the default locale (probably Windows-1252) with slightly different error handling so it should give a similar error message.  Windows-1252 (Western Europe) doesn't support the `Čč` characters, but Windows-1250 (Central and Eastern Europe) and Windows-1257 (Baltic languages) do.  You can see what is handled with `.encode('ansi','replace')`

Comment: @Brian61354270: I import the created file into an ERP system. It is written in FoxPro with an underlying MS-SQL database. If the file is in UTF-8, imported German and Slovenian characters are shown corrupt in the ERP dialogues. If it is in ANSI, the ERP shows it correct. This is the reasen why I need it in ANSI.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi: Notepad++ shows "ANSI" to me in the status bar. If it shows "ANSI", the strings from imported files will be shown properly in the ERP system.

Comment: If I import the codecs module and select as output encoding "cp1250" (it should include German AND Slovenian) instead of "ansi", the script does run without error messages! Notepad++ tells me, that created file with German and/or Slovenian characters would be in ANSI. Files without national characters would be in UTF-8 (is OK). But it makes from Slovenian character "Č" (hex C8) (in the input-CSV) an "È" in the output-file (and also will be so imported into ERP). So Python does not store Slovenian characters properly despite the cp1250.

Comment: Python3 store Unicode strings (+ extra), but in an internal encoding, and it allows all Unicode characters. And as I understood from your comment, it wrote correctly to a file. Then there is an additional complexity (`print`) will print in console, and with possible a system encoding. I do not know which encoding is using your system. You may need to check (and it should be compatible on how console will interpret the output of your program, so setting it in python will not solve the full problem).